# How to find last date of the month in IBM app connect?

Tags: datetime, ibm-integration-bus

Usually you can get this using LAST_DAY in esql but in app connect it's not working anyone has any idea on how to get last day of the month using esql in app connect?

Comment: Usually best to use Half-Open approach in date-time handling.  Test for “is before the first day of following month” rather than “is equal to or earlier than last day of month”.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is I want to set the value to a variable not just verify.

Comment: In case anybody is wondering...ESQL has never had a LAST_DAY function. It's available in SQL, but not in ESQL.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem I used intervals to get the next month then set the next month's date value to 1 and use interval again to get the day before, which will be the last date of the month in question.
Basically I checked the next month and got next month's 1st date which will always be 1 then got the day before that which will always be the last date of current month.